# how to convert the float 9.88 number to integer 9 in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I'm want to this `$scope.Numberpage` in  correct interger value not in point or float value. I'm using the jquery function but i want to used any angular js function or method.thanks in advance.

```
$scope.Numberpage = Math.ceil(response.data['data'].length/7);
```

Comment: Your question is not clear and posted without any research. This is not jQuery this is plain JavaScript. From your question explanation `Math.floor` should work fine for `$scope.Numberpage` to be initialized with an integer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any jquery here, this is all good as its plain js.

Answer (score 0):

Angular has no math, use `Math.floor()` javascript function.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that Angular doesn't provide such thing to convert float to int.
But you can use pure javascript like this,

```
$scope.Numberpage=parseInt(response.data['data'].length/7);
```

have you tried this?